# Select records which not created yet for certain column value

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

There are two tables:

```
content_term
    cid | tid
    1 | 1
    1 | 2
    1 | 3
    2 | 4
    2 | 5
    2 | 6

term_group
    tid | gid
    1 | 1
    2 | 2
    3 | 3
    4 | 1
    5 | 2
    6 | 3
```

How is possible to select "cid" not linked to certain "gid" through "tid"?

**UPD**
I've tried Adrian's way with grouping by cid:

```
SELECT cid 
FROM   content_term ct 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT tid 
               FROM   term_group tg 
               WHERE  tg.tid = ct.tid 
                      AND tg.gid = 4) GROUP BY cid;
```

And also tried Adrian's way with grouping by cid:

```
SELECT cid FROM content_term
    LEFT JOIN term_group ON (content_term.tid = term_group.tid AND gid = 4)
    WHERE gid IS NULL GROUP BY cid;
```

On "gid" = 3 or any other value - both of them returned:

```
cid
1
2
```

Comment: Which means all of the `cid`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cid FROM content_term
    JOIN term_group ON (content_term.tid = term_group.tid AND gid = 4);
```

will map all cid's with gid 4. We now require all cids in `content_term` that are *not* in this list. So we use a `LEFT JOIN` between the unique cids and the attached cids we have just retrieved:

```
SELECT unique_cids.cid FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT cid FROM content_term ) AS unique_cids
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT cid FROM content_term
       JOIN term_group ON (content_term.tid = term_group.tid AND gid = 4) )
           AS attached_cids ON (unique_cids.cid = attached_cids.cid)
    WHERE attached_cids.cid IS NULL;
```

Testing:

```
CREATE TABLE content_term ( cid integer, tid integer );
CREATE TABLE term_group ( tid integer, gid integer );
INSERT INTO content_term VALUES (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6);
INSERT INTO term_group VALUES (1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,1),(5,2),(6,3);
```

First try with gid 4:

```
SELECT unique_cids.cid FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT cid FROM content_term )
   AS unique_cids
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT cid FROM content_term        
JOIN term_group ON (content_term.tid = term_group.tid AND gid = 4)) 
          AS attached_cids ON (unique_cids.cid = attached_cids.cid)
     WHERE attached_cids.cid IS NULL;

+------+
| cid  |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Retry with gid 3:

```
SELECT unique_cids.cid FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT cid FROM content_term ) 
    AS unique_cids
     LEFT JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT cid FROM content_term
        JOIN term_group ON (content_term.tid = term_group.tid AND gid = 3))
            AS attached_cids ON (unique_cids.cid = attached_cids.cid)
     WHERE attached_cids.cid IS NULL;

Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I've tried your query with grouping: `SELECT cid FROM content_term LEFT JOIN term_group ON (content_term.tid = term_group.tid AND gid = 4) WHERE gid IS NULL GROUP BY cid;` returned same for 3 and 4. But 4 does not attached to any content yet.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I made two stupid mistakes; I have edited the answer, and tested it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cid 
FROM   content_term ct 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT tid 
                   FROM   term_group tg 
                   WHERE  tg.tid = ct.tid 
                          AND tg.gid = 4)
```

Comment: Thanks for formatting :) Your query does exactly what I need, but when I put existing "gid" = 3, I got "cid" which are already attached, I mean result set should be empty if "gid" = 3.